# scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] to DataFrame ? error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have some `sql.Row` objects that I wish to convert to a `DataFrame` in Spark 1.6.x

My Rows look like:

```
events: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = List([14183197,Browse,80161702,8702170626376335,59,527780275219,List(NavigationLevel, Session)], [14183197,Browse,80161356,8702171157207449,72,527780278061,List(StartPlay, Action, Session)])
```

Printed Out:

```
events.foreach(println)
[14183197,Browse,80161702,8702170626376335,59,527780275219,List(NavigationLevel, Session)]
[14183197,Browse,80161356,8702171157207449,72,527780278061,List(StartPlay, Action, Session)]
```

So I created a schema for the data;

```
 val schema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("trackId", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("location", StringType, true),
    StructField("videoId", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("id", StringType, true),
    StructField("sequence", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("time", StringType, true),
    StructField("type", ArrayType(StringType), true)
  ))
```

And then I attempt to the create the `DataFrame` by :

`val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(events, schema)`

But I get the following error;

```
   error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
  (data: java.util.List[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rows: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
```

I not sure why I get this, is it because the underlying data in the `Row` has no type information ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to `parallelize`:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(events), schema)
```

Comment: thanks, however I get some casting error `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.math.BigInt cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`, not sure why as I haven't declared types anywhere